# How to understand the version PRE?

Tags: version-control, version, spring-cloud

There are some different versions in Spring Cloud, how to understand `PRE` here? Is it `preview`?? If so, what is the difference from `SNAPSHOT`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a 'pre' release: a milestone `M*` or a release candidate `RC*`. SNAPSHOT can be unstable because it can change with every deploy (bleeding edge). Milestones and Release candidates a fixed releases, to try out, but not use in production.